# Get all user control in C# project

Tags: c#

I have created a few UserControls.  I want to add all the UserControls in my project to `List<UserControl>`.

I have read a few topics about this issue but I can't get it working.
I have tried getting all UserControls in a namespace but it still doesn't work.

```
var controlType = typeof(UserControl);
var controls = controlType
            .Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => controlType.IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
                        t.Namespace == "AgentManagement.UserInterface.SystemUI"
            );
```

Comment: UserControl is System class? if you want to fetch your created usercontrol, should get local assembly

Comment: "it still not work" is not clear.

Comment: Try adding some more information to your post on what you've tried, what errors you get when it "doesn't work" and what you expect to happen. The more information the better!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're getting the assembly of the `UserControl` class which is in System. What you want to do is get your classes derived from `UserControl` which, obviously won't be in the System assembly.

What you want to do is calling, for example:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t => controlType.IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
                    t.Namespace == "AgentManagement.UserInterface.SystemUI");
```

Or, if it's not in the executing assembly, something like

```
typeof(OneOfYourUserControl).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(...);
```

Comment: I want to get all user control has been created.

Comment: I want to get all user control has been created.
Example:
I have a dynamic menu context.
I want when go call event "Click", a user control will be open(that user control name and item in menu will be compare by database).
if i have user control "ucAccount"
i have to do ucAccount _ucEx = new ucAccount(); 
but i have a lot user control and i want to do it automatic.

Comment: Yes, that's what you should get with the code I wrote in my answer. Doesn't it work?